# Why I'm not being registered as a client?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming

As far as I know [`Network.isClient`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network-isClient.html) should return `true` when I am connected to a server, specifically on a Unity `MasterServer`. But it does not.

I have these 2 lines of code:

```
Network.Connect(hostData);
Debug.Log("Is client? " + Network.isClient);
```

In the console they return:

```
//NetworkManager: Running as client. No player ID set yet.
//Is client? False
//NetworkManager: Connected to <my IP:PORT>
//NetworkManager: Set player ID to 1
```

Since it says "Running as client" you would think that I am running as a client. But `Network.isClient` is returning `false`. Later in my program I call this as well, after the player ID is set but `Nework.isClient` is still returning `false`.

So how is this supposed to work? Currently I am circumventing this by saying `!Network.isServer` which should be OK as long as the player is connected.

Comment: Have you tried your debug check within OnConnectedToServer()? I believe Network.Connect is asynchronous.

Comment: @Chris That was it, after a client connects i immediately switched scenes, in the next scene `Start()` method I did `isClient()` but this was to fast for the player really being connected. I still find it awkward i get the Console feedback like mentioned above, they should change that to save headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait. Connect needs some time because of [delays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_delay) and other processes.

You add your code [OnConnectedToServer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.OnConnectedToServer.html) method and check it here.
Like

```
void OnConnectedToServer() {
   Debug.Log("Is client? " + Network.isClient);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it is almost instant but not instant enough. Thanks